# Register class to the DI engine of IServiceCollection

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm a bit new in this so be easy with me :D
I creaed a web api project based on .net core 6.

i'm trying to find a way to register all the classes i want to the DI engine.
in .net framework 4.7.2 i used castle windsor that way:

```
 _container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory)));
```

that was called to all the classes in all the project was implemented the IWindsorInstaller wiht the install method and there i was registred the classes of the same project (i had one infrastructure class handled the registration).

i'm searching kind of the same way in .net core to do so.
from the program.cs trigger something that will call all the classes that will handle the registration.

all other projects in my web api main solution are class libreries.

tnx

Comment: There is nothing build in for this. You need to use 3rd party container to support this or write some code based on reflection.

Comment: but like what? i tried a lots of ways to it with reflection, but if my other projects are not referenced in the main web service project (that project when you create web api template project in VS), i can't find them by reflection.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nuget package called Scrutor that can scan assemblies for classes that implement an interface and then register them into the service collection

https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor

Example:

```cs
var collection = new ServiceCollection();

collection.Scan(scan => scan
    .FromAssemblyOf<ITransientService>()
    .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<ITransientService>())
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .WithTransientLifetime()
```